# Is there a way to aggregate elastic search "day level indices" to single "month level index"?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I have an elastic search and its capacity is at 85% and it will withstand only for the next few days as I keep indexing.

**I don't want to delete any index as of now.**

But is there a way to merge all day level index to a single month level index, for example I index data to ES everyday, can I make changes to older index so that it can represent each month.

Is there a technique to do it? If so, will it provide me additional space?

Your inputs will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely move all older daily indices to a monthly one and then delete the daily indices and keep only the monthly one using the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html).

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": ["2016-07-01", "2016-07-02", ..., "2016-07-31"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "2016-07"
  }
}
```

By doing so, and assuming you have an alias spanning all of your daily indices, you're going to improve the query time a little bit since instead of querying all the shards of 30+ indices, you're only going to query the shards of a single index. That's definitely a good thing to do, provided you pick the right number of shards for your new monthly index.

Another thing to attempt before reindexing would be to try to [call the `force_merge` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html) on your daily indices to try to expunge the deleted documents (`?only_expunge_deletes=true`) and see if that makes some room on your system.

In any case, merging indices together + expunging deleted document will buy you some room but don't expect the capacity to increase drastically. You'll probably need to increase the size of your hard disk at some point.